# Underscorejs - change values in JSON array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an array of json objects from the server:

```
var a = [
{id:1,name:"Piano",class:"Instrument"},
{id:2,name:"Guitar",class:"null"},
{id:3,name:"null",class:"null"},.....]
```

Using underscorejs, is it possible to loop through these objects and change every `"null"` value in every key with empty string `""`?

Comment: Yes, it is completely possible. It is also possible in plain javascript. Did you try anything? What did you have a problem with?

Comment: I've tried with underscore but without success. I need tto change every null value in this array with empty string.

Comment: What was your code and how was it not a success?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate through the collection and its objects using [`_.each()`](http://underscorejs.org/#each)* method and replace the values equal to "null" with the empty string.
So the logic is the same as you were iterating through two-dimensional array using nested loop.

* I don't suggest to use `_.map()` here since this method will produce new modified array and I don't know if you need this, though if you want you can also map the array using `_.each(obj)` inside the mapping function.

```js
var arr,
    searchVal,
    replaceVal;

arr = [
  {id: 1, name: "Piano", class: "Instrument"},
  {id: 2, name: "Guitar", class: "null"},
  {id: 3, name: "null", class: "null"}
];

searchVal = "null";
replaceVal = "";

_.each(arr, function(obj) {
  _.each(obj, function(value, key) {
    if(value === searchVal) {
      obj[key] = replaceVal;
    }
  });
});

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping through all the data after being parsed from your JSON string, you could just create a custom parser for JSON.parse and save yourself some time.

```js
function customParser(key, value) {
    if (value.name === 'null') {
        value.name = '';
    }
  
    if (value.class === 'null') {
        value.class = '';
    }

    return value;
}

var jsonText = '[{"id":1,"name":"Piano","class":"Instrument"},{"id":2,"name":"Guitar","class":"null"},{"id":3,"name":"null","class":"null"}]',
    a = JSON.parse(jsonText, customParser);

document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(a)));
```